# Como comparar apenas parte de uma String em Java

Tags: java, string

```
String str = new String("Bruno Oliveira");
String str2 = new String("Gustavo Oliveira");

System.out.println(str.equals(str2)); //retorna false
```

Como comparar apenas determinada parte de uma string?

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer. Que parte? Em programação as coisas precisam ser bem definidas.

Comment: Quero comparar o Oliveira.

Comment: Queria informar uma mensagem.

Comment: Tu quer tratar só a parte depois do espaço?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno ele morreu :D

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você queria algo do tipo:

```
    String str = new String("Bruno Oliveira");
    String str2 = new String("Gustavo Oliveira");

    //cria array de strings usando o espaço como separador
    String[] arr = str2.split(" ");

    // busca na string alvo cada pedaço da string separada
    for (String s : arr) { 
        if (str.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println("match: " + s);
        }
    }
//retorno
//match: Oliveira
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei entendi o que você realmente precisa, mas pelo entendi você quer localizar uma *substring* dentro de uma *string* e comparar se a *substring* está contida em outra *string*, se for realmente isso, você poderá usar o método *contains* (da primeira *string* em associação com o método *substring* da segunda *string*.
No exemplo abaixo, passei os índices iniciais da *substring*. Talvez não seja a melhor abordagem, pois nem todos os textos tenham o tamanho fixo, mas é apenas para exemplificar.

```
    String s = new String("Bruno Oliveira");
    String s1 = new String("Gustavo Oliveira");
    System.out.println(s.contains(s1.substring(8,16)));
```